# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.5'

Tags: python, csv, integer

I am writing a program that gathers a GTIN number from the user so that they can purchase an item. However, when trying to multiply the price by the quantity, I get the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'
```

With x being the price in the CSV.

My Code is as follows:

```
import csv
import sys
import re
import os

addItem = ""
gtinNum = ""
quantity = 0
totalPrice = 0
restart = ""

f = open("ChocolateCSV.csv", "rt")

def restart():
    restart = input("Would you like to restart? Y/N")
    global receiptCont
    receiptCont = receipt.read()

    if restart.lower() == "y":
        gtinQuestion()
    else:
        receipt.close()
        print(receiptCont)
        sys.exit()

def quantityQuestion():
    quantity = input("How much would you like?")
    global price
    price = ""

    with open("ChocolateCSV.csv", 'r') as file2:
        for row in csv.reader(file2):
            if str(gtinNum) in row:
                receipt.write(str(row) + "\n")
                receipt.write(str("- Quantity: " + quantity + "\n"))
                price = int(row[2]) * quantity
                receipt.write("- Price: " + str(price))
                restart()

def scanGTIN():
    global rows
    rows = re.split('\n', f.read())

    for index, row in enumerate(rows):
        global cells
        cells = row.split(',')
        if gtinNum in cells:
            quantityQuestion()

def gtinQuestion():
    global gtinNum
    global receipt
    receipt = open("receipt.txt", "r+")
    gtinNum = input("Please enter the GTIN-8 Code of the product you would like to order:")

    if gtinNum.isdigit() == False or len(gtinNum) != 8:
        gtinQuestion()
    elif gtinNum.isdigit() == True and len(gtinNum) == 8:
        scanGTIN()


gtinQuestion()
```

Comment: The error message looks pretty clear. What is your question?

Comment: The error message is confusing at first: it's saying you're trying to convert the string "x" into an integer.  Check what row[2] is, and remember list indexes start at 0.

Comment: @Tony Row[2] is the final column, which is just a number and nothing else.

Comment: @BlackBear How do I avoid it so that the calculation goes through?

Comment: Is `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'` exactly the error as it appears, or are you saying that the error message contains some number in place of "x", and you're just calling it "x" in this question because it varies? I'm guessing it's the latter since your title contains an actual number.

Comment: @Kevin Correct, 'x' is a placeholder for a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"0.5" is not a value that can be turned into an integer, because integers can only represent whole numbers, not fractions.

```
>>> s = "0.5"
>>> int(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.5'
```

Consider using `float` instead, or possibly `Decimal` if you require exact precision. (always a good thing when it comes to money.)

```
>>> float(s)
0.5
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(s)
Decimal('0.5')
```

Comment: The float has worked, I also forgot to place int(quantity) instead of just quantity. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The only time you use `int()` in your code is in line 36,

```
price = int(row[2]) * quantity
```

That row comes from the file `ChocolateCSV.csv` which you do not provide, so we cannot be specific on the cause of your error. But obviously there is an `'x'` character in the string `row[2]`. Check exactly what that string is and why there is an 'x' in it. As @Tony pointed out, you may have the index off by one.

You see what that string is by placing this line just befor the `price =` line:

```
print(repr(row[2]))
```

and look at the printed strings just before you get the error. In other words, use basic debugging strategies. (I used `repr()` so you can easily tell the difference between a string and an integer or other such type.)

Comment: There isnt an 'x' in the column. Im using 'x' as a placeholder for the multiple different integers in the column.

Comment: @Jordan: Then you should show the *exact* error you got, with the full traceback. The debugging strategy should still work.